# What's the actual meaning of "sits down to a banquet of consequences" in this sentence?

Tags: expressions, metaphors, figurative-language

> Sooner or later everyone sits down to a banquet of consequences.
> — *Robert Louis Stevenson*

I don't find any relevant definition for the phrasal verb "sits down". And what's the thought behind the expression "banquet of consequence"?

Comment: It's a slightly peculiar figurative usage, conveying elements of *[have to] **eat your words*** and *[have to] **lie on the bed** [you made]*. The reason it's "odd" is because sitting down to a banquet (*not* a "stand-up buffet") is normally a *good* thing. But as is usually the case when someone says or alludes to ***Actions have consequences,*** the implication is ***bad consequences***. Look up ***chickens coming home to roost*** for a near-synonym in common use today.

Comment: It is just writing. a banquet is a feast. The metaphor here is about a rich array of food and drink. **One sits down to a meal in English**. Here, a banquet. It is very creative. Metaphors rarely have "actual" meanings. It's for you to imagine.

Comment: @Lambie: I'd say it ***is*** slightly "peculiar", because the word ***banquet*** here is being used ***facetiously*** as well as figuratively (implying ***a lot*** of bad things, but nothing you'd want to "feast" upon). Of course, that needn't imply it's stylistically defective - as you say, it's ***creative***.

Comment: It's a banqueting version of "you've made your bed now sleep in it".

Comment: … or "you reap what you sow." I like it. It implies 'a lot of consequences', presumably as advice/warning to someone doing a lot of 'bad' things. I'd like to see the fuller context, tbh. Google isn't of immediate help, as the quote appears to have reached 'meme status', throwing the source too far down the list to be worth the effort of filtering it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an extended metaphor.

So we metaphorically consider "consequences" to be food. Eating the food is metaphorically getting the effects of those consequences. Lots of food which is prepared and ready to be eaten is a banquet, so "a banquet of consequences" is when there are a large number of the consequences ready to have an effect. I would expect these "consequences" to be the result of bad actions, and so have a bad effect.

And to eat a banquet, you sit at the table, and you are expected to eat all the meals.

This isn't a familiar or well-known metaphor, but if you make the observation that "banquet of X" means that X is the food served, then you follow through the analogy it should all become clear.

Comment: What is a standard metaphor? There are tons of metaphors that none of us here have ever encountered....

Comment: Standard metaphors are ones like "you must reap what you sow" or "you've made your bed, so you;ll have to sleep in it".  These are familiar sayings.  Perhaps "familiar metaphor" would be better than "standard metaphor".

Comment: This is a good answer, and I'd like to deduct only half a point, as this isn't really an "extended" metaphor, at least not in the sense that term is used in lit-crit, where it refers to a primary metaphor being reinvoked multiple times in a passage by the use of additional figurative language taken from the domain of the primary metaphor. For example, if Stevenson later in the passage should refer to suffering "indigestion" later in life from the excesses of youth, to give a fairly crude example of such a trope.

Comment: I think one can say "saying", aphorismss or truisms but not metaphor for those. A metaphor is: His eyes are moony orbs.

Comment: "metaphor" is wider that just X is Y,  it occurs when you use one thing to carry the meaning of another.  Here "consequences are food", and the rest is an extended metaphor.